# How to fix this nested for loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, jupyter-notebook, nested-loops

I'm writing a loop to go through 2 lists and print sentences out of them but it's not working.

I've tried changing up the syntax but nothing is working.

```
states = ["virginia", "new jersey", "north carolina", "california"]
capitals = ["richmond", "trenton", "raleigh", "sacramento"]

for x, name in enumerate(states):
    for y name in enumerate(capitals):
        print("The capital of " + states[x] + "is " + capitals[y] + ".")
```

This is the error I keep getting.

```
File "<ipython-input-11-9f2d009ec38f>", line 2
    for y name in enumerate(capitals):
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Did you mean to not put a `,` (comma) in the second loop?

Answer (score 2):

The invalid syntax is because you are missing ',' between y and name.

Anyway, you can use the build-in function `zip`.

```
for state, capital in zip(states, capitals):
    print("The capital of " + state + "is " + capital)
```

Comment: Nice one, I always forget about `zip()`. You should change "is " to " is " though otherwise it will print weirdly (OP should do this too!)

Comment: @Reedinationer hmmm... You are right! I skip this part. Usually, I prefer to use `format` or ',' instead of '+' (comma will add spaces by itself).

Comment: Wow that was a really simple solution. I didn't even know the zip function existed. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You missed a "," in your second for loop
`for y, name in enumerate(capitals):`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a nested for loop is necessary here. Your lists are the same length, so `enumerate()` is already telling you the index. I would simplify it to:

```
states = ["virginia", "new jersey", "north carolina", "california"]
capitals = ["richmond", "trenton", "raleigh", "sacramento"]

for x, name in enumerate(states):
    print("The capital of " + name + " is " + capitals[x] + ".")
```

Which yields:

> The capital of virginia is richmond.
>
> The capital of new jersey is trenton.
>
> The capital of north carolina is raleigh.
>
> The capital of california is sacramento.

Answer (score 0):

There is not need for nested loop here, as you have one-to-one relation in your data (every state has 1 capital and every capital has 1 state). You could use `zip` to create pairs or if you wish to use index value inside for loop you could do:

```
states = ["virginia", "new jersey", "north carolina", "california"]
capitals = ["richmond", "trenton", "raleigh", "sacramento"]
for i in range(len(states)):
    print("The capital of "+states[i]+" is "+capitals[i])
```

or using so called [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/):

```
states = ["virginia", "new jersey", "north carolina", "california"]
capitals = ["richmond", "trenton", "raleigh", "sacramento"]
for i in range(len(states)):
    print(f"The capital of {states[i]} is {capitals[i]}")
```

In both case output is:

```
The capital of virginia is richmond
The capital of new jersey is trenton
The capital of north carolina is raleigh
The capital of california is sacramento
```

Note that my method will work correctly if number of elements of `states` is equal to number of elements of `capitals`.